# keep existing image if no new image selected

Tags: php, database, image

In an Events form, I'm trying to keep (update with) the existing image if no new image is uploaded. The rest of the form retains the info like location, time, etc. 
But when trying to use existing image (which does show before you hit update) after you hit update the existing image disappears and does not include itself in the update. I'm an amateur. .. your help is appreciated.  below are some codes:

```
   function eventadd(){

    if($_REQUEST['startampm'] == 'PM') $_REQUEST['starthour'] += 12;
    $datetimescheduled =        $_REQUEST['startyear'].'-'.$_REQUEST['startmonth'].
                        '-'.$_REQUEST['startdate'].' '.$_REQUEST['starthour'] .
                        ':'.$_REQUEST['startminute'].':00';

    $filetmp = $_FILES['file_img']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['file_img']['name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['file_img']['type'];
    $filepath = "flyers/".$filename;


    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

          $query = 'insert into eventcalendar '.
            '(dateentered,datetimescheduled,title,location,description,img_name,img_path,img_type,soldout,private,free,paydoor,ticketlink,ticketURL) '.
            'values '.'(now(),"'.$datetimescheduled.'","'.stripslashes($_REQUEST['title']).'","'.addslashes($_REQUEST['location']).'","'.stripslashes($_REQUEST['description']).'","'.$filename.'","'.$filepath.'","'.$filetype.'","'.addslashes($_REQUEST['soldout']).'","'.addslashes($_REQUEST['private']).'","'.addslashes($_REQUEST['free']).'","'.addslashes($_REQUEST['paydoor']).'","'.addslashes($_REQUEST['ticketlink']).'","'.addslashes($_REQUEST['ticketURL']).'")';


            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
```

Here is the update form, where the image does not retain:

```
// update existing event action
if($updateevent) {

if($startampm == 'PM') $starthour += 12;
$datetimescheduled = $startyear.'-'.$startmonth.'-'.$startdate.' '.$starthour .':'.$startminute.':00';

// added to try to fix update image
$filetmp = $_FILES['file_img']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['file_img']['name'];
$filetype = $_FILES['file_img']['type'];
$filepath = "flyers/".$filename;
// end fix - also see image name field didnt work

move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

$query = 'update eventcalendar set '.
        'datetimescheduled = "'.$datetimescheduled.'",'.
        'title = "'.stripslashes($title).'",'.
        'location = "'.addslashes($location).'",'.
        'description = "'.stripslashes($description).'",'.
        'img_name = "'.$filename.'",'.
        'img_path = "'.$filepath.'",'.
        'img_type = "'.$filetype.'",'.
        'soldout = "'.stripslashes($soldout).'",'.
        'private = "'.stripslashes($private).'",'.
        'free = "'.stripslashes($free).'",'.
        'paydoor = "'.stripslashes($paydoor).'",'.
        'ticketlink = "'.stripslashes($ticketlink).'",'.
        'ticketURL = "'.stripslashes($ticketURL).'"'.
        'where id = '.$id;



$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
```

The HTML form excerpt:

```
<td align="right">IMAGE:</td>
            <td><input name="file_img" type="file"><?php echo $row['img_path'] ?><?php echo '<img src='. $row['img_path'] .' class="img-responsive no-img thumb-img">'; ?><br>
```

Again, when submitting this HTML form with no new image, the existing image does not update with itself.

All I get:  FLYERS/   (NO IMAGE NAME)
although it shows with : `<img src='. $row['img_path'] .`

but does not include itself after hitting `SUBMIT`.

Comment: yeah, this script is about 10 years old, found it somewhere it works except for issue above. And I did say to myself that it had to be out of date by now.. I will modify a more modern script that is safe. Thanks for confirming. !!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, mysql_query is outdated, hence, you should be using mysqli_query.  Passing variables in a query is not recommended as it encourages sql injection - it is recommended that you use prepared statements.

To answer your question, you can check to see if an image is uploaded before doing the update.  The solutions would be to ignore the image columns if an image has not been uploaded or select the existing image from the database.  Here is an example which selects the existing image from the database if an image has not been uploaded using prepared statements(code has not been tested):

```
$filetmp = $_FILES['file_img']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['file_img']['name'];
$filetype = $_FILES['file_img']['type'];
$filepath = "flyers/".$filename;
// end fix - also see image name field didnt work

move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

 // if a file has not been uploaded get the flyer from the DB
  if(empty($filename))
    {
      // CHANGE $connection variable to whatever your db connection is called
      $select_image = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT img_name, img_path, img_type FROM eventcalendar WHERE id = ? ");
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($select_image, 'i', $id);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($select_image);
       mysqli_stmt_bind_result($select_image, $filename, $filepath, $filetype);
       mysqli_stmt_fetch($select_image);
       mysqli_stmt_close($select_image);
     }

  // CHANGE $connection variable to whatever your db connection is called
   $query = mysqli_prepare($connection, "UPDATE eventcalendar SET datetimescheduled = ?, title = ?, location = ?, 
description = ?, img_name = ?, img_path = ?, img_type = ?, soldout = ?, private = ?, 
free = ?, paydoor = ?, ticketlink = ?, ticketURL = ? WHERE id = ? ");

   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'sssssssssssssi', $datetimescheduled, stripslashes($title), addslashes($location), 
stripslashes($description), $filename, $filepath, $filetype, stripslashes($soldout), stripslashes($private), 
stripslashes($free), stripslashes($paydoor), stripslashes($ticketlink), stripslashes($ticketURL), $id);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
    mysqli_stmt_close($query);
```

Comment: thank you for the help Johanne. I tried the addition above, got this error for the mysqli lines:  Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null ..  I appreciate it .. Any way to add code that fits/matches the outdated code?  safe or not ?

Comment: Did you change the $connection variable (variable name where you do mysqli_connect) to what you called yours?

Also mysql_query has been removed from PHP 7, so it makes no sense using it.

Comment: I believe so, changed $connections with my database table namename 'Eventstics' - it did connect hope that's what you meant. got about 13 errors related to mysqli, I assume its because the outdated code? maybe ?

Comment: What are the errors?  You can start updating your code by changing to mysqli_*** wherever there is mysql_***

Comment: Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /event_admin.php on line 63
Query failed : Query was empty   -    So I have 33 instances of MySQL - so change them to mysqli .. ? .. could not list all errors - 13 in all ..

Comment: "So I have 33 instances of MySQL - so change them to mysqli .. ?"

Yes, that will be a good start